# Is it possible to stream double values from an array using scanner?

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio-2.0

I have a method that needs single values as the input, but I only have the information in an array. I have searched and found out that Scanner can stream values but only in string form. So I thought I should change the array into string and then convert it back into double before returning the value.

Here is what I had written.

```
    double E;
    public double StreamValue (double[]g2){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(Arrays.toString(g2)); //PROBLEM HERE
        while (s.hasNext()){
            E = Double.parseDouble(s.next());
        }
        return E;
    }
```

When I ran the code, it failed. My question is, is the idea right but I'm missing any part, or it's completely invalid?

Edited:

I need to feed the streaming values into a methode that will analyze each values and return an int.

This is kind of a short example of it:

```js
 public int EventAnalyzer(double E) {
   if (E > c_max)
      a = 0;
   else
     a = 1;
   return a;
   }
```

The returned value will be used for this method:

```js
private void isDetected (int a){
        CharSequence t0 = "No breathing";
        CharSequence t1 = "Normal breathing";
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.apnea);

        if(a==0)
            textView.setText(t0);
        if(a==1)
            textView.setText(t1);
       
    }
```

Comment: Could you specify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is completely invalid. There is no more evil than toString() and back. Also, your function is not reenterable, does not stream anything and parses the whole array to get last value, while you can directly access last element in array.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin  okay, I can see that now. Any idea I can achieve the result I need?

Comment: You can get DoubleStream from array with Arrays.stream(g2) and use it as stream. Please provide code that uses your EventAnalyzer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alexander Anikin had answered the question in the comment. I'm working on the Arrays.stream but it requires API 24 while I have API 19. I'm looking for other way possible. Thanks everyone for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not completely clear to me, but
if you have `double[] g2`:

You can use an enhanced `for`-loop:

```
for(double d : g2)
    System.out.println("This is a double from array: "+ d);
```

If you need to return one double from the array, then you can retrieve it using the index by doing

```
return g2[x];
```

where x is a valid index between `0` and `g2.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your idea is right.

But your result E must be an array of double:

```
double[] E;
```